# По какому ресурсу изучать ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Новичок в С#, до этого писал на python/Django, знаю php/Laravel. Нужен ресурс для изучения asp.net core 3+. Нашел курс на Ютубе, но он для версии 2.0. Можно ли смотреть его, а потом перейти на версию 3.1? Если нет, то подскажите, по каким источникам изучали asp.net core вы.

Comment: Вообще актуальная версия - 6, но сойдет и 5. 3.1 уже уходит в прошлое, а 2.0 "уже всё". Советую учить как можно ближе к актуальной версии. Нет особого смысла консервировать бэкенд в эпохе динозавров, особенно в случае с ASP.NET Core, так как миграции между версиями относительно безболезненные.

Comment: Мне кажется родная документация у микрософта очень неплоха. Удивляет нежелание людей в 21 веке читать официальную документацию :)